# Python not appending dictionary from API

Tags: python

I am trying to pull a list of Players from the current PGA tournament that the ESPN API will give.  In the JSON file I show that "Sam Burns" is the last player so I am assuming it is not appending the players before.  I do receive one line of data shown below, any thoughts see code below as well.

Current results:

```
     game_id               date        name playerName
0  401580329  2024-01-04T05:00Z  The Sentry  Sam Burns
```

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

# Define the API endpoint
api = 'https://site.web.api.espn.com/apis/site/v2/sports/golf/leaderboard?league=pga'

# Make a GET request and get the JSON response
response = requests.get(api)
data = response.json()


# Extract the events data, which contains the game details
events = data['events']

# Create an empty list to store the game data
games = []

# Loop through each event and get the relevant information
for event in events:
    # Get the game id, date, status, and competition
    game_id = event['id']
    date = event['date']
    name = event['name']
    for competition in event['competitions']:
        for competitor in competition['competitors']:
            athlete = competitor['athlete']
            playerName = athlete['displayName']

    # Create a dictionary with the game data
    game = {
        'game_id': game_id,
        'date': date,
        'name': name,
        'playerName': playerName
    }

    # Append the game dictionary to the games list
    games.append(game)

# Convert the list of dictionaries into a pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(games)

print(df)
```

Comment: Indent the definition of `game` and the `append()` two levels so that they happen for each competitor.

Comment: JonSG --- You are a bloody genius!!  Thank you such simple mistake that I wont be making anytime soon :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is in the indentation of the line where you define the player **(playerName)**. Specifically in this section:

```
for competitor in competition['competitors']:
    athlete = competitor['athlete']
    playerName = athlete['displayName']

# Create a dictionary with the game data
game = {
    'game_id': game_id,
    'date': date,
    'name': name,
    'playerName': playerName
}
```

In other words, the code block to create the game dictionary is outside the loop that iterates over the competitors. This means that the value of playerName will be only from the last competitor.

To fix this, you need to adjust the code indentation to ensure that the dictionary creation is inside the for loop for competitor in competition['competitors']. Here a Example:

```
# Loop through each event and get the relevant information
for event in events:
    # Get the game id, date, status, and competition
    game_id = event['id']
    date = event['date']
    name = event['name']
    for competition in event['competitions']:
        for competitor in competition['competitors']:
            athlete = competitor['athlete']
            playerName = athlete['displayName']

            # Create a dictionary with the game data
            game = {
                'game_id': game_id,
                'date': date,
                'name': name,
                'playerName': playerName
            }

            # Append the game dictionary to the games list
            games.append(game)
```

With this modification, the **game** dictionary will be created for each competitor, ensuring that all players are included in the final list.

Answer (score 0):

Way to much work you're doing. Let pandas flatten out that json:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

# Define the API endpoint
api = 'https://site.web.api.espn.com/apis/site/v2/sports/golf/leaderboard?league=pga'

# Make a GET request and get the JSON response
data = requests.get(api).json()

df = pd.json_normalize(data,
                       record_path=['events', 'competitions', 'competitors'],
                       meta=[['events', 'id'], ['events', 'date'], ['events', 'name']])

cols = ['events.id', 'events.date', 'events.name', 'athlete.displayName']
df = df[cols]
```

**Output:**

```
print(df.to_string())
    events.id        events.date               events.name      athlete.displayName
0   401580335  2024-02-15T05:00Z  The Genesis Invitational               Nick Hardy
1   401580335  2024-02-15T05:00Z  The Genesis Invitational           Denny McCarthy
2   401580335  2024-02-15T05:00Z  The Genesis Invitational        Xander Schauffele
3   401580335  2024-02-15T05:00Z  The Genesis Invitational               J.J. Spaun
4   401580335  2024-02-15T05:00Z  The Genesis Invitational            Kurt Kitayama
5   401580335  2024-02-15T05:00Z  The Genesis Invitational              Adam Schenk
6   401580335  2024-02-15T05:00Z  The Genesis Invitational              J.T. Poston
7   401580335  2024-02-15T05:00Z  The Genesis Invitational                Eric Cole
8   401580335  2024-02-15T05:00Z  The Genesis Invitational                Luke List
9   401580335  2024-02-15T05:00Z  The Genesis Invitational          Collin Morikawa
10  401580335  2024-02-15T05:00Z  The Genesis Invitational             Taylor Moore
11  401580335  2024-02-15T05:00Z  The Genesis Invitational                Cam Davis
12  401580335  2024-02-15T05:00Z  The Genesis Invitational          Sahith Theegala
13  401580335  2024-02-15T05:00Z  The Genesis Invitational            Wyndham Clark
14  401580335  2024-02-15T05:00Z  The Genesis Invitational         Nicolai Højgaard
15  401580335  2024-02-15T05:00Z  The Genesis Invitational               Sungjae Im
16  401580335  2024-02-15T05:00Z  The Genesis Invitational             Brian Harman
17  401580335  2024-02-15T05:00Z  The Genesis Invitational                Jason Day
18  401580335  2024-02-15T05:00Z  The Genesis Invitational          Charley Hoffman
19  401580335  2024-02-15T05:00Z  The Genesis Invitational               Tony Finau
20  401580335  2024-02-15T05:00Z  The Genesis Invitational              Matt Kuchar
21  401580335  2024-02-15T05:00Z  The Genesis Invitational               Chris Kirk
22  401580335  2024-02-15T05:00Z  The Genesis Invitational             Brendon Todd
23  401580335  2024-02-15T05:00Z  The Genesis Invitational             Rory McIlroy
24  401580335  2024-02-15T05:00Z  The Genesis Invitational            Gary Woodland
25  401580335  2024-02-15T05:00Z  The Genesis Invitational            Rickie Fowler
26  401580335  2024-02-15T05:00Z  The Genesis Invitational              Nick Taylor
27  401580335  2024-02-15T05:00Z  The Genesis Invitational               Adam Scott
28  401580335  2024-02-15T05:00Z  The Genesis Invitational                 Kevin Yu
29  401580335  2024-02-15T05:00Z  The Genesis Invitational           Viktor Hovland
30  401580335  2024-02-15T05:00Z  The Genesis Invitational        Taylor Montgomery
31  401580335  2024-02-15T05:00Z  The Genesis Invitational             Ludvig Åberg
32  401580335  2024-02-15T05:00Z  The Genesis Invitational               Lee Hodges
33  401580335  2024-02-15T05:00Z  The Genesis Invitational              Ben Griffin
34  401580335  2024-02-15T05:00Z  The Genesis Invitational            Cameron Young
35  401580335  2024-02-15T05:00Z  The Genesis Invitational           Keegan Bradley
36  401580335  2024-02-15T05:00Z  The Genesis Invitational                  Tom Kim
37  401580335  2024-02-15T05:00Z  The Genesis Invitational              Tiger Woods
38  401580335  2024-02-15T05:00Z  The Genesis Invitational            Chase Johnson
39  401580335  2024-02-15T05:00Z  The Genesis Invitational              Nick Dunlap
40  401580335  2024-02-15T05:00Z  The Genesis Invitational            Justin Thomas
41  401580335  2024-02-15T05:00Z  The Genesis Invitational            Byeong Hun An
42  401580335  2024-02-15T05:00Z  The Genesis Invitational           Harris English
43  401580335  2024-02-15T05:00Z  The Genesis Invitational           Russell Henley
44  401580335  2024-02-15T05:00Z  The Genesis Invitational           Grayson Murray
45  401580335  2024-02-15T05:00Z  The Genesis Invitational            Jordan Spieth
46  401580335  2024-02-15T05:00Z  The Genesis Invitational            Andrew Putnam
47  401580335  2024-02-15T05:00Z  The Genesis Invitational          Tommy Fleetwood
48  401580335  2024-02-15T05:00Z  The Genesis Invitational              Adam Hadwin
49  401580335  2024-02-15T05:00Z  The Genesis Invitational         Hideki Matsuyama
50  401580335  2024-02-15T05:00Z  The Genesis Invitational          Emiliano Grillo
51  401580335  2024-02-15T05:00Z  The Genesis Invitational             Séamus Power
52  401580335  2024-02-15T05:00Z  The Genesis Invitational          Patrick Cantlay
53  401580335  2024-02-15T05:00Z  The Genesis Invitational             Beau Hossler
54  401580335  2024-02-15T05:00Z  The Genesis Invitational                 Tom Hoge
55  401580335  2024-02-15T05:00Z  The Genesis Invitational             Lucas Glover
56  401580335  2024-02-15T05:00Z  The Genesis Invitational          Patrick Rodgers
57  401580335  2024-02-15T05:00Z  The Genesis Invitational         Mackenzie Hughes
58  401580335  2024-02-15T05:00Z  The Genesis Invitational                Sam Ryder
59  401580335  2024-02-15T05:00Z  The Genesis Invitational               Si Woo Kim
60  401580335  2024-02-15T05:00Z  The Genesis Invitational              Sepp Straka
61  401580335  2024-02-15T05:00Z  The Genesis Invitational                 Max Homa
62  401580335  2024-02-15T05:00Z  The Genesis Invitational         Matt Fitzpatrick
63  401580335  2024-02-15T05:00Z  The Genesis Invitational            Corey Conners
64  401580335  2024-02-15T05:00Z  The Genesis Invitational            Adam Svensson
65  401580335  2024-02-15T05:00Z  The Genesis Invitational  Christiaan Bezuidenhout
66  401580335  2024-02-15T05:00Z  The Genesis Invitational        Scottie Scheffler
67  401580335  2024-02-15T05:00Z  The Genesis Invitational             Alex Smalley
68  401580335  2024-02-15T05:00Z  The Genesis Invitational           Will Zalatoris
69  401580335  2024-02-15T05:00Z  The Genesis Invitational                Sam Burns
```